# Is this an example of a dangling modifier?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, dangling-participles

Dangling modifiers occur when it is unclear to which word a descriptive part of sentence applies. A classic example would be "She left the room fuming" -- is it "she" or the room that's fuming?

But how about this sentence:

> I found her in the library, studying history.

Could the intended meaning -- it was *her* who was studying history -- be misinterpreted to mean that I found her while *I* was studying in the library? Likewise, could the sentence be parsed to lead to the absurd interpretation that the *library* was doing the studying?

Comment: I don't see how it could be interpreted in a way that meant the library was studying history. But the other two possibilities are there, though by far the most likely interpretation would be that she was the one studying history. The ambiguity remains if you add *whilst*, before *studying*.

Comment: Dangling participles tend to become problematic only when they are front-shifted, as in "[While] studying history, the library was her constant haunt." Such a front-shifted participial phrase strongly tends to be read as having for its subject the most immediately following noun or noun phrase, which is generally the subject of the main clause; and here that leads to absurdity, in that libraries do not themselves study history. In "I found her in the library, studying history," the possibility of misreading seems to me to be negligible.

Comment: @Brian: Personally, I think that rule is just a little silly.  Everyone *knows* the library is not studying history, so why should it be so important to avoid implying such?

Comment: Lose the comma intonation (and the comma, of course, in writing) and it becomes unambiguous. You found her, she was in the library studying history. If you make it parenthetical with intonation, the question arises as to why, and that leads to an ambiguity search.

Comment: I would be inclined to say that "finding (a person)" and "studying history" are both active endeavors that a single person is unlikely to pursue at the same time, making the sentence less ambiguous than if "found" were "met" or "stumbled into", or some other more passive activity.  (And, to be clear, I'm not talking about active/passive in the grammatical sense.)

Comment: Commas are often helpful in disambiguating. Contrast the phase construction _He went singing_ with the free modifier construction _He went, singing_. Again: _Behind the dense bushes the outlaws stood watching the sheriff's men in the village below_ // _Behind the dense bushes the outlaws stood, watching the sheriff's men in the village below_.

Comment: @Kevin It's not a rule—it's just how the language works and is parsed by her speakers. Avoiding constructions that are likely to cause ambiguities or garden path situations is just a courtesy to the listener/reader. While grammatically acceptable, you're just a more considerate writer if you take a little time to consider what you're writing and try to avoid them. (See what I did there? Did you not at some point in that sentence pause have to start again with how your brain had started parsing it?)

Comment: @Janus: "See what I did there? Did you not at some point in that sentence pause have to start again with how your brain had started parsing it?": No, actually, I didn't see it.  I had to backtrack and look for it when I saw your parenthetical.

Comment: @Kevin How about (from an old newspaper article, via Wikipedia, slightly altered) “Having been missing for two years, Walter P. Stanley, III, left, found all the old records of the Bangor Lions Club”? Personally, I had to backtrack _twice_ in that one.

Answer (score 1):

If you substitute a modifier possible for all three, is it then hopelessly unclear ?  For example

I found her in the library without any books!

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It is obvious that the library is not studying history; that would be absurd! When replaced with something that would be less obvious, however, the sentence still directs the modifier at "her". Check it: "I found her in the library, on fire". Because of the comma, the modifier cannot be directed at the object immediately before it. The comma almost acts as a buffer, redirecting the modifier to an earlier subject. If you think of the reason for that, the comma almost makes the sentence into a list: "I found her in the library, studying history, and eating a baguette". Thus the "in the library" and "studying history" are placed as parallels in the sentence.